# Cache Video while loading

Tags: objective-c, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, asihttprequest

I tried to search both on the site and google, but I could not find anything. 
I want to save the MPMoviePlayerController cache of a video stream. 
I tried with different libraries like ASIHttpRequest and others but I can't play the video until it is finished downloading. 
Is possible to save the cache or play while downloading?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution for that problem?